# I have Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SET

Tags: sql, error-handling, google-bigquery, syntax-error

Here is my code but I keep getting the error message Syntax error:

> Unexpected keyword SET at [4:1]

```
SELECT start_station_id
FROM `cyclist-bike-share-success.Trip_data_2022_.April_2022`, 
UPDATE `cyclist-bike-share-success.Trip_data_2022_.April_2022`,
SET start_station_id='unknown',
WHERE start_station_id IS NULL
```

Any advice?

Comment: You seem to have random extra commas in your sql. Specifically before `SET` and before `WHERE`

Comment: Seems like you need to learn about delimiters and line breaks. For example if you replace all of the comma `,` characters here with line breaks your query would be much more readable and probably work without error. These two queries don't actually need any commas, but you'd normally put those between column names. Technically each statement should be terminated with a `;` character (and SQL Server will be enforcing this in a future release), so here you'd insert one at the end of the `SELECT` statement (before the `UPDATE` keyword) and one at the end of the `UPDATE` statement after `IS NULL`.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or big query? Please only tag the relevant rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the documentation about how to write queries.

For your question, try to write like below:

```
SELECT start_station_id
FROM `cyclist-bike-share-success.Trip_data_2022_.April_2022`; 
UPDATE `cyclist-bike-share-success.Trip_data_2022_.April_2022`
SET start_station_id='unknown'
WHERE start_station_id IS NULL
```